# How to select a field with Mongodb Core Query API matching my criteria

Tags: java, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a need to select only one field name (categoryName) from my collection matching my criteria. Instead all fields are returned from the collection for the following code:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
public ServiceList findOneByCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Query query = new Query() ;
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categoryName").is(categoryName));
    return (ServiceList) mongoTemplate.findOne(query,ServiceList.class);
}
```

ServiceList.java

```
@Document(collection = "services")
public class ServiceList {
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    @Field("categoryName")
    @JsonProperty("categoryName")
    private String categoryName;
    
    @Field("serviceTypes")
    @JsonProperty("Service Types")
    private List<ServiceType> serviceTypes;

    public String getMfServicesId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setMfServicesId(String mfServicesId) {
        this.id = mfServicesId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public List<ServiceType> getServiceTypes() {
        return serviceTypes;
    }

    public void setServiceTypes(List<ServiceType> serviceTypes) {
        this.serviceTypes = serviceTypes;
    }
    
 }
```

For this code, all fields are returned from the collection. I don't know how to select specific field that i chose to display.

Comment: Could you please include your document models like ServiceList and any embedded documents you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked to select and display a specific column from a document using **include** function.

```
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
 public ServiceList findOneByCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    Query query = new Query() ;
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categoryName").is(categoryName));
    query.fields().include("categoryName");
    return (ServiceList) mongoTemplate.findOne(query,ServiceList.class);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work, using the `fields()` method:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categoryName").is(categoryName));
query.fields().include("categoryName");
query.fields().exclude("id"); // Not sure you have to exclude Id explicitly
return (String) mongoTemplate.findOne(query,String.class);
```

Comment: Doing so resulted in an error. Include and exclude method cannot be used at the same time. Either one of them can be used. But i got your idea

Comment: Id has to be excluded explicitly as mongo fetches Id field by default with the following code:
          query.fields().exclude("id");